# Corrupt file when using Azure Functions External File binding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, binding, onedrive, azure-functions

I'm running a very simple ExternalFileTrigger scenario in Azure Functions were I copy one created image file from one onedrive directory to another.

function.json

```
    {
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "apiHubFileTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "Bilder/Org/{name}",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "Bilder/Minimized/{name}",
      "connection": "onedrive_ONEDRIVE"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

run.csx

```
using System;

public static string Run(string input, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# File trigger function processed: {name}");
    return input;
}
```

Every things seems to work well BUT the new output image file i corrupt. The size is almost twice as big.
When looking at the encoding the original file is in ANSI but the new generated file from Azure Functions is in UTF-8.
It's working fine when I'm using a text file when source encoding is UTF-8.

Is it possible to force Azure binding ExternalFileTrigger to use ANSI? Or how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 2019: The external file binding seems to be deprecated from the current version of Azure Functions.

---

If you want to copy the file as-is, or do more fine-grained binary operations on the file contents, I recommend using `Stream` type instead of `string` for your input and output bindings:

```cs
public static async Task Run(Stream input, Stream output, string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        var byteArray = ms.ToArray();
        await output.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    log.Info($"C# File trigger function processed: {name}");
}
```

Change the ouput binding in `function.json`:

```
  "name": "output",
```

This function will do exact binary copy of the file, without conversion.

You can see which other types you can use for bindings in [External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file) (see "usage" sections).

Comment: When using Stream the target file will be 0 bytes big. I tried to set position to 0 before the return with no luck.

Comment: @MartinHolm Yes, posted a sample that actually works

Comment: Great! Tried it out and as you said this will be an exact binary copy.
Thanks mate.

Comment: The link to "External File bindings" doesn't seem to be working (as of 2019-07-17). There's a redirect to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#supported-bindings and I can see External File in that list ???

Comment: Checked Way Back Machine and the page has dropped the External binding ... https://web.archive.org/web/20170710142234/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file